# (Robotium) How to select a RadioButton in a RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, robotium

In my Android app view layout, I have a `<RadioGroup>` which contains two `<RadioButton>`:

```
<RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/my_radio_group"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

      <RadioButton 
       android:id="@+id/yes_btn"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/yes"
      />

     <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/no_btn" 

       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/no"
      />
</RadioGroup>
```

I use **[Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/)** library to write a **JUnit test** for this radio group **to selection one Radio Button**. The test code snippet is:

```
Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity()); 
...
solo.clickOnRadioButton(R.id.yes_btn); //I expect the "yes" radio button will be selected
```

I expected the above test code would select the "YES" Radio button, But when run it, it raise an **error**:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 2131427675 RadioButtons are not found!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:417)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOn(Clicker.java:374)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnRadioButton(Solo.java:1063)
...
```

How can I select one `<RadioButton>` in a `<RadioGroup>` then with **[Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/)**??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) solo.getView(R.id.yes_btn);
solo.clickOnView(rb);
```

solo.clickOnRadioButton() takes view index as argument, while you are passing Resource ID.